# Copy a folder and create a new folder for each month

Tags: copy

I have very little experience programming, so I'm not not sure if the following can be done.

I need to copy files from a folder and put them into another location for backup. I would like to copy the folder once a month and put the files into a backup folder labeled for that month and year.

My source folder is C:\Users\Company Name\Documents\Global S Programs

My destination folder is I:\Quality\CMM Global S programs\

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I found this simple code to copy the files, create a new folder, label it with the current date and year and then paste the files into it.
Than I just set up the task scheduler to run it once a month.
I ended up changing the order of the date to MMDDYYYY.
To get MMDDYYYY change line 6 to this "ds=%%B_%%C_%%A"( %%A=Year %%B=Month %%C=Day)

```
 @Echo Off
    Set "sd=C:\Users\Company Name\Documents\Global S Programs"   
    Set "dd=I:\Quality\CMM Global S programs"    
    If Not Exist "%sd%\" Exit /B
    For /F "Tokens=1-3Delims=/ " %%A In ('RoboCopy/NJH /L "\|" Null'                                                   
    M   D   Year
    ) Do If Not Defined ds Set "ds=%%A_%%B_%%C" 
    If Not Defined ds Exit /B
    RoboCopy "%sd%" "%dd%\%ds%" /E
```